# How can I make sure the std::vector allocated memory give back to operating system after deallocating?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, operating-system, glibc

The code below is calling `foo` and use `while(1)` to watch the memory usage. As I know, after 'finished' printed, `var d` is deallocated and the STL container will free the data space(heap) by himself.

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

void foo() {
  std::vector<std::string> d(100000000);
  for(int i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) d[i] = "1,1,3";
  d.resize(0);
  d.shrink_to_fit();
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  foo();
  std::cout << "finished" << std::endl;
  while(1) {;}
  return 0; 
}
```

But what I observed(using `htop`): memory is not freed back to the operating system. This is just a bench and the real code related to `MESOS` which has memory limitation for each process.

I have tried several versions of compiler such as g++-4.7.2 g++-4.8.1, clang++ on linux server with glibc 2.15. More, I also use tcmalloc instead of default malloc, but it still do not work(in MAC machine the problem will not happen).

What's the problem? How can I make sure the memory give back to os?
Thank you.

Comment: Someone else may be able to point it out in the standard, but based on [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) page `delete` just has to deallocate memory, it is not specified that it must return it to the OS right away.  If you want to guarantee that, you may need to write your own versions of `new` and `delete` which use your OS' function calls and ensure the memory is actually returned to the OS.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I make sure the memory give back to os?

You can terminate your process.

> What's the problem?

There probably isn't one.  It's normal for programs not to return memory (though Linux does return memory early for some particularly large allocations).  They normally use `sbrk` or equivalent to grow the virtual address space available to them, but it's not normally worth the effort of trying to return deallocated memory.  This may be counter-intuitive, but it's also proven workable for millions of programs over many decades, so you shouldn't bother yourself with it unless you have a specific tangible problem.  It shouldn't cause problems for you as the deallocated memory will be reused when the application performs further allocations, so the "MESOS memory limitation for each process" you mention still affects the "high watermark" of maximum instantaneous memory usage the same way.

Note that OSes with [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory) support may swap long unused deallocated pages to disk so the backing RAM *can* be reused by the kernel or other apps.

It's also possible to take manual control of this using e.g. memory mapped files, but writing such allocators and using the from Standard containers is a non-trivial undertaking... lots of other SO questions on how to approach that problem.

Answer (score 1):

Allocating memory from the OS has two downsides:

1. High overhead. A system call involves a switch into protected mode which takes much longer than a simple function call, and then the memory management for the OS itself is probably quite complex.
2. High granularity. The OS probably has a minimum size allocation like 4K. That's a lot of overhead for a 6 byte string.

For these reasons the C++ memory allocator will only ask the OS for large blocks, then parcel out pieces of it when asked via `new` or `malloc`.

When those pieces of memory are released, they're put back into a pool to be handed out again on the next request. Now it's quite possible that *all* of the pieces of a larger block end up being freed, but how often does that happen in real life? Chances are that there will be at least one allocation per block that sticks around for a long time, preventing the block from being returned to the OS. And if it *is* returned, what do you think are the chances that the program will turn around and request it back again a short time later? As a practical matter it usually doesn't pay to return blocks to the OS. Your test program is a highly artificial case that isn't worth optimizing for.

Answer (score 0):

In most modern systems the operating system manages memory in pages. Application memory is managed in pools (heaps) by library functions. When your application allocates memory, the library functions attempt to find an available block of the size you requested. If the memory is not in the pool, the library calls the system to add more pages to the process to incorporate into the pool(heap). When you free memory it goes back into the pool. The allocated pages in the pool do not return to the operating system.